# Way to create file with the box api

Tags: box-api

I there a way to create a doc, like a .boxnote into a third app with the box api ? It seems that only edit, delete update functionalities are avaible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is not possible.

Box Notes are created using an specific web application from Box. But Box's API only have [two modules](https://developers.box.com/docs-overview/) :

- **Box Content**: for managing the upload/download of data
- **Box View**: for converting docs to HTML